# NullPointerException in while loop

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate the total call duration of every contact in given period from call log, but I stuck with this NullPointerException in my while loop:

```
Cursor c = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                int[] duration = new int[c.getCount()];
                String[] name = new String[c.getCount()];

                do{
                    boolean w = false;
                    int y=0;
                    do{
                        if(name[y].equals("")){
                            name[y]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                            duration[y]+=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)));
                            w = true;
                        }else if(name[y].equals(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)))){
                            duration[y]+=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)));
                            w = true;
                        }
                        y++;
                    }while(w);
            }
```

The error accurs in if statment where `if(name[y].equals(""))`
The cursors projection ant selection seems to work fine.

Here`s my stack trace:

```
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dailyreports.ainius/com.dailyreports.ainius.ReportView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at com.dailyreports.ainius.DataProvider.getTotalCallDuration(DataProvider.java:1359)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at com.dailyreports.ainius.DataProvider.getReportData(DataProvider.java:109)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at com.dailyreports.ainius.ReportView.onCreate(ReportView.java:139)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
10-22 07:36:18.429: E/AndroidRuntime(27320):    ... 11 more
```

Im sure its an easy one, but I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked your c.getCount() value? I guess it returns zero.

Comment: Wouldn`t it throw arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this case? Anyway, I checked and it doesn`t return zero.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The default value for string type in java is null and as you haven't initialized your array members, they are all null so you are calling null.equals("").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] name = new String[c.getCount()];
```

This line will create an array of size `c.getCount()` but all the indexes will be filled with `null`.

and you are using index 0, without initializing it. and hence NPE.

You can change your `if` condition to following to avoid NPE and thus to initialize array in first iteration:

```
if(name[y] == null)
```

It'll be better if you could explain what are you trying to achieve. I see problems in your logic.

Comment: Your solution worked and there was problem in my logic: the second while statement should have been `while(!w);`

Answer (score 2):

if name[y] is null, calling a method on it like "equals()" will throw an NPE. By looking at your code, I think you need to change the if statement to

```
if(name[y] == null || name[y].equals(""))
```

And as Azodious mentioned, after initializing the array, all entries will be null.

Answer (score 0):

before actually accessing the name[y] , check if index `y` is in the range of `name` array. If it exists, then you can check `if` the content in that `index` is `null`.

```
if(y<name.length() && name[y]!=null)
 { 
   **access name at y index** and do stuffs
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    if(c.getCount() > 0){ // i add this additional condition
        int[] duration = new int[c.getCount()];
        String[] name = new String[c.getCount()];
        boolean w = false;
        int y=0;
        do{
            if(name[y] != null && name[y].equals("")){
                name[y]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                duration[y]+=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)));
                w = true;
            }else if(name[y].equals(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)))){
                duration[y]+=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)));
                w = true;
            }
            y++;
        }while(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: will still cause an NPE here: `if(name[y].equals(""))`